# After getting substring from a string, get the rest of the string that was cut

Tags: php, string

I have a variable that contains string which may or may not contains more than 350 characters.

so to get the first 350 characters, I can use `*substr()*` to get the first 350 characters

```
$mainString = "Content which is greater than or less than 350 characters";
$subString = substr($mainString, 0, 350);
```

This gives me first 350 characters. Now I need those characters after 350th index, let's say from 351 to 400.

How do I get the remaining?

One logic that I had was, to get the length of the string and use *`substr`* to get characters from 350 to the `strlen($mainString)`

Comment: Your logic sounds promising, did you implement it?

Comment: An alternative approach would be to use a stream to read the string. That way you can read exactly 350 chars. Then, when you read on, you read from where you stopped before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$mainString = "Content which is greater than or less than 350 characters";
$cutPos = 350;

$subString = substr($mainString, 0, $cutPos);
$restofString = substr($mainString, $cutPos, strlen($mainString));
```

Comment: Please provide explanation to how this is solving the OP's problem.

Comment: He needs the rest of the string, after 350´s cut, so i understand him.
With this sniped he can access the first 350 characters and also all after the cut. Or did i miss understand anything?

Comment: I was reviewing your post. You've provided a solution, but it's policy to write some explanation to why this is solving the problem in your answer, either in comments in the code, or in the answer itself. (latter is preferred).

Comment: Oh, ok, thanks for your info, i will think about it in my next posts.